PowerShell script that will replace a second octet in an IP and Default Gateway
I am new here and would appreciate some help. I need to replace the second octet in an IP from 42 to 41. I managed to figure something out but it is not working on the Default Gateway part. Any idea?
Error
$oldIP = (Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0).IPAddress
$oldDG = (Get-wmiObject Win32_networkAdapterConfiguration | ?{$_.IPEnabled}).DefaultIPGateway

$newIP = $oldIP -replace 42, 41
$newDG = $oldDG -replace 42, 41

#Write-Output $newIP $oldIP
#Write-Output $newDG $oldDG

New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -IPAddress $newIP -PrefixLength 28 -DefaultGateway $newDG

Error
New-NetIPAddress : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'DefaultGateway'. Cannot convert value to type System.String.
At line:12 char:95
+ ... s Ethernet0 -IPAddress $newIP -PrefixLength 28 -DefaultGateway $newDG
+                                                                    ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-NetIPAddress], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,New-NetIPAddress
 

@Mathias,
This is the error I am getting when running your script
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:15 char:1

$dgOctets = $oldAdapterConfig.IPv4DefaultGateway.Split('.')

  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull




Cannot index into a null array.
At line:18 char:1

$dgOctets[1] = '41'

  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray




New-NetIPAddress : Invalid parameter DefaultGateway
At line:21 char:1

New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -IPAddress $newIPAddress - ...

  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_NetIPAddress:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPAddress) [New-NetIPAddress], CimException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 87,New-NetIPAddress




There are two problems with your code, only one of which is currently surfacing.
When you use Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |? {$_.IPEnabled} to query for the adapter configuration, you risk getting all IP-enabled adapter configurations on the machine, not just the one associated with the interface you want to update.
To get the configuration specifically associated with the assigned IP address, pipe the NetIPAddress instance Get-NetAdapter:
# fetch existing ip assignment and adapter config
$oldIPAssignment = Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -AddressFamily IPv4
$oldAdapterConfig = $oldIPAssignment |Get-NetAdapter

Now you'll only get one adapter config, and thus a single gateway address.
The second problem is using -replace to replace a particular octet.
If the old IP address is 10.42.10.142 then you'll end up changing it to 10.41.10.141 instead of 10.41.10.142.
Instead, split the IP address into its 4 constituent octets and modify/replace the second one separately.
# split existing IP into 4 separate octet strings
$ipOctets = $oldIPAssignment.IPAddress.Split('.')

# update 2nd octet and construct new IP address
$ipOctets[1] = '41'
$newIPAddress = $ipOctets -join '.'

# split existing DG IP into 4 separate octet strings
$dgOctets = $oldAdapterConfig.IPv4DefaultGateway.Split('.')

# update 2nd octet and construct new DG IP address
$dgOctets[1] = '41'
$newDGAddress = $dgOctets -join '.'

New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -IPAddress $newIPAddress -PrefixLength 28 -DefaultGateway $newDGAddress


Wow, thank you very much, I will analyze your work and test. Will let you know shortly.

@Marcin did you run the first two lines before attempting the update?

@Marcin I'll add that the Get-WmiObject is obsolete in Powershell 5.1 and has been removed in Powershell Core so for any new code it'd be better to replace it with its substitute Get-CimInstance which was introduced back in 3.0

@sirtao The Get-Net* commands are CIM cmdlets, so that solves that problem :)

@MathiasR.Jessen, yes, I ran all lines from your code.

@MathiasR.Jessen Good to know, though I was telling it as a general info for Marcin not specifically about your answer

After checking Mathias' suggestion and other sources I managed to find on the Internet I came up with the below which works for me. Hope it might help someone else.
#finding IPv4 address
$ip = (Get-NetIpaddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -AddressFamily IPv4).IPAddress

$ipoctet = [byte[]]($ip -split '\.')
$ipoctet[1]=91
$newip = $ipoctet -join '.'

#finding Subnet mask
$mask = (Get-NetIpaddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -AddressFamily IPv4).PrefixLength

#finding DG address
$dg = (Get-NetRoute '0.0.0.0/0').NextHop 
$dgoctet = [byte[]]($dg -split '\.')
$dgoctet[1]=91
$newdg = $dgoctet -join '.'


#Write-Output $newip
#Write-Output $newdg

Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 | Remove-NetIPAddress -Confirm:$false
Remove-NetRoute -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -NextHop $dg -Confirm:$false
New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -IPAddress $newip -PrefixLength $mask -DefaultGateway $newdg

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"

